# Trouble using SendGrid with appharbor

Tags: sendgrid, appharbor

I am using appharbor, added SendGrid as addon,
They provided me 
smtp host - smtp.sendgrid.com
port - 587
user - 32adf793-2cbf-492c-9bb9-************@apphb.com

When I use these details and try to send email via my c# code,
it says, "Failure Sending Email". Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AppHarbor injects the relevant SMTP configuration in your application's configuration and you can send emails right off the bat using this snippet:

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Send(new MailMessage(...));
```

There are additional details [here](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/sending-emails).