# AppHarbor, Elmah, and SendGrid

Tags: elmah, appharbor, sendgrid

Is there any magic that AppHarbor does with Elmah and SendGrid?

I see from this question [Trouble using SendGrid with appharbor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968518/trouble-using-sendgrid-with-appharbor) that AppHarbor does some configuration so an SMTP client can be initialized without parameters. I'm not sure what configuration is performed and whether it would apply to Elmah.

Elmah has a custom  tag in the web.config but will it read the settings that AppHarbor configures by default?

Edit:
If Elmah can't read those settings by default is there a way to use tokens to get replaced during the appharbor deploy process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put all the glue together thanks to a little testing and these two links:

http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/managing-environments
http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/05/21/163350.aspx

AppHarbor (I assume) is adding the SendGrid variables to <system.net> mailSettings in the web.config and Elmah will honor those settings. For a more secure configuration, you can add the useSsl="true" flag to <errorMail>

All I needed to add was the following:

```
<elmah>
    <!-- AppHarbor clears App_Data on each deploy -->
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
    <errorMail from="error@a.com"
      to="admin@a.com"
      subject="Application Exception"
      async="false"
      smtpPort="0"
      useSsl="true"
    >
    </errorMail>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
</elmah>
```

AppHarbor and Elmah took care of the rest.